# UIWebView size does not match storyboard

Tags: ios, uiwebview, storyboard, size

I cannot figure out why but the size of my UIWebView in my storyboard does not match the size when I run the app on my device. You can see from the images below: in the storyboard, there is lots of gray space below the web view, but on my device, there is only a little gray space.

[image: lots of gray space]

[image: little gray space]

What I want is for the bottom of the web view to line up with the top of the tab bar, but if I line it up in the storyboard, the web view will extend below the tab bar when I run it on my device.

[image]

Comment: Did you set any auto layout constraints?

Comment: No, I didn't set anything. See added image above.

Comment: Are you designing in storyboard for a 4 inch screen but testing on a 3.5" screen?

Comment: then you can try programmatically set height of WebView
like, WebViewHeight=screenHeight-tabBarHeight

Comment: You should definitely set constraints and not rely on the runtime/build time generated constraints.

Comment: How do I tell/set what size screen my storyboard is in? I would like the bottom of the web view to line up with the top of the tab bar, no matter which device is being used. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by selecting my web view in the storyboard, and then going to Editor->Pin and selecting four options: "Leading Space to Superview, Trailing Space to Superview, Top Space to Superview, and Bottom Space to Superview". This has the effect of "sticking" the edges of the web view to the edges of the screen, no matter which device is being used. I learned about these autolayout properties from [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[image]